# Functional equation Dedekind zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, l-functions, zeta-functions

I'd like to know to what point is it possible to generalize 
[this method](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Zeta_Riemann/functional_equation_dedekind_zeta_function_by_ideal_class.html)
 for obtaining the **functional equation** for the Dedekind zeta function $\zeta_K(s)$ of a number field ?

---

Let $\mathfrak{C}$ be the ideal class group
$$\zeta_K(s)  =\sum_{I \subset \mathcal{O}_K} N(I)^{-s} = \sum_{C_j \in \mathfrak{C}} \ \ \sum_{I \subset \mathcal{O}_K,I \,\sim \, C_j} N(I)^{-s}$$
Assuming $\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ is finite, each ideal $C_j \in \mathfrak{C}$ being a rank $n=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ free $\mathbb{Z}$-module  with basis $b_{j,1}, \ldots, b_{j,n}$, letting $C_j C_j^{-1}  = (d_j)$ :
$$\zeta_{K,C_j}(s)=\sum_{I \subset \mathcal{O}_K,I \,\sim \, C_j} N(I)^{-s} = \frac{1}{|O_K^\times|} \sum_{a \in C_j^{-1}}  N(\frac{a}{d_j} C_j)^{-s}$$ $$=\frac{1}{|O_K^\times|}\frac{N(C_j)^{-s}}{N(d_j)^{-s}}\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus (0)} N(\sum_{l} m_l b_{j,l})^{-s}$$
$$\Gamma(s) \zeta_{K,C_j}(s) = \frac{1}{|O_K^\times|}
\frac{N(C_j)^{-s}}{N(d_j)^{-s}}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1} \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus (0)} e^{-x\ N(\sum_{l} m_l b_{j,l})}dx$$
Therefore it reduces to finding a Poisson summation formula for $\displaystyle\Theta_j(x) = \sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^n} e^{-x \, N(\sum_{l} m_l b_{j,l})}$.

- [I did it for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Zeta_Riemann/functional_equation_dedekind_zeta_function_by_ideal_class.html) whose ideal class group has two elements, obtaining that $$\Lambda(s)= 5^{s/2}\pi^{-s}\Gamma(s)4 \zeta_{\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})}(s)=\Lambda(1-s) $$ I guess this method works at least for any imaginary quadratic field ?
- If $K$ is imaginary quadratic, $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[w]$ and any ideal has the form $(k,l+ow)$ then due to the property of $2\times 2$ matrices (see how $\scriptstyle\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 0 & \sqrt{5}\end{pmatrix}$ is treated [in the link](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Zeta_Riemann/functional_equation_dedekind_zeta_function_by_ideal_class.html)), I'll get a functional equation $\Lambda_{K,C_j}(s) = \lambda_j^{s/2} \pi^{-s}\Gamma(s)\zeta_{K,C_k}(s)=\Lambda_{K,C_j}(1-s)$, but I don't know how to show $\lambda_j $ is the same for each ideal class $C_j$.
- What about the other cases ($\mathcal{O}_K^\times$ infinite, cubic extension, non-monogenic field...) ?

Comment: Didn't Hecke do this for any number field?  Isn't it in his book Algebraic Number Theory?

Comment: @Stopple : He shows the Poisson summation formula of the theta function of an ideal in the Minkowski space [p.215 eq.(180) and (185)](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Hecke-Lectures.on.the.theory.of.algebraic.numbers.pdf) $\theta(x) = \sum_{a \in I} e^{-\pi (\sum_{m=1}^n x_m |\sigma_m(a)|^2)}$ where $\{\sigma_m\}_{m=1}^n$ is the Galois group. But he doesn't mention the functional equation for $\zeta_K(s)$

Comment: I'm writing exactly this proof up for the notes in my ongoing algebraic number theory course and will post a link when done.

Comment: There are also versions in Lang's and Neukirch's ANT books and I think also in Weil's "basic number theory".

Comment: @LiorSilberman [Neukrich does it](http://www.paris8.free.fr/Algebraic%20Number%20Theory%20-%20Neukrich.pdf) p.218, but his notation is horrible.

Comment: You can write the integral explicitly; Lang does it and so will I.

Comment: @LiorSilberman : He might be doing something like this $ \displaystyle\iint_{(\mathbb{R}^+)^n} (x_1\ldots x_n)^{s-1} \exp(-\sum_{m=1}^n |\sigma_m(a)|^2 x_m)dx= N(a)^{-2s} \Gamma(s)^n$ where $\sigma_m$ are the complex embeddings, $N(a) = |\prod_{m=1}^n \sigma_m(a)|$ and so we can use the Poisson summation formula for the $\theta$ function in the comment above

Comment: @reuns You are correct about what is in Hecke's book; surprising to me - what's the point of the Poisson summation argument except to prove the functional equation and analytic continuation?  Stark, in "The analytic theory of algebraic numbers", sketches the proof and credits Hecke, but without a specific reference.

Comment: @Stopple I can't say exactly but he looks at the Poisson summation formula for the $\theta$ twisted by a character, and things like the class number, the quadratic reciprocity ...

Comment: @reuns: Hecke is continuing not just the Dedekind zetafunction but also L- functions of Hecke characters.

Comment: Continuing the L-function of a character does require the twisted version of Poisson sum.  It shouldn't require quadratic reciprocity; rather, the Gauss sum enters the formula (and thus contributed to the root number).

Comment: I asked a new question about the main step for obtaining the Poisson summation formula for the $\theta$ function : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2224969/reciprocal-basis-of-an-ideal-in-mathcalo-k @LiorSilberman

Comment: @Stopple ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You ask a similar type question at MSE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2224969/reciprocal-basis-of-an-ideal-in-mathcalo-k You claim in the above post that from a theorem on an inverse operator $T^{-1}$ you get a proof of the functional equation for the Dedekind zeta function - can you explain this proof? In the above link you make some references to the litterature but this seems not to be correct.

Answer (score 4):

In any event, this is essentially Hecke's original argument, the only other truly independent known proof being that of Tate. The original paper (in german) is, I believe,

- Erich Hecke "Über die Zetafunktion beliebiger algebraischer Zahlkörper" (1917)

The method works for arbitrary number fields and, with some extra work, for any twist by a Hecke character.

English expositions of the proof can be found at least in Neukirch and Lang's textbooks.

Comment: In fact, Hecke's paper is clearer than the account in Lang, I think.